# Open documents in browser with zoho api

Tags: api, document, zoho

HI im trying to integrate zoho into my website and open a document in browser
Im using Wamp server.

This the code im trying to work with:

```
 <html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<form method="POST" action="http(s)://export.writer.zoho.com/remotedoc.im" target="_self" 

accept-charset="UTF-8">
<input type="hidden" name="url" value="http://localhost/paper.doc">
<input type="hidden" name="apikey" value="here goes api key">
<input type="hidden" name="output" value="url">
<input type="hidden" name="mode" value="normaledit">
<input type="hidden" name="filename" value="paper.doc">
<input type="hidden" name="lang" value="en">
<input type="hidden" name="skey" value="here goes secret value">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="12345678">
<input type="hidden" name="format" value="doc">
<input type="hidden" name="saveurl" value="http://localhost/save.php">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Open/Edit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I dont know i get this error:
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /http(s)://export.writer.zoho.com/remotedoc.im on this server.

I have entered the api key correctly and the secret key
Im just confused and stuck here.Im blocked

Here is the documentation : http://apihelp.wiki.zoho.com/Open-Document.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have taken the (s) out of the url right? I know it might seem like a silly question but I thought I should check in case you had overlooked it.  The url resolves for me and gives an 'api key is invalid' warning.

The error given would seem to indicate the browser thinks its a relative instead of absolute url.

Comment: thanks..again i get this error   RESULT=FALSE
ERROR_CODE=1841
WARNING=Unable to import content    ..thnaks il try to solve :)

Answer (score 0):

I dont know much more about ZOHO but i also want to implement this in my project in future. As i read in https://apihelp.wiki.zoho.com/Open-Document.html#mfs it says that saveurl must be publicly accessible and if it not accessible publicly it gives an error and localhost is not publicly accessible so it gives an error.